# Error in AWS DMS Endpoint using Oracle database as a source

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, endpoint, dms

I have tried to configure an AWS DMS Endpoint, but when I try to do the connection test it shows me the following error:

> Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Log Miner is not supported in Oracle PDB environment Endpoint initialization failed.

I have given all the grants that are required in Oracle DB following the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html

But the error still persists. What could be the solution?

Comment: As per the same documentation that you link above, Oracle LogMiner doesn't support connections to a pluggable database (PDB). To connect to a PDB, access the redo logs using **Binary Reader**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to extra connection attributes (under endpoint settings)

```
useLogMinerReader=N;useBfile=Y;
```

make sure to grant necessary permission to your container user on this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html#CHAP_Source.Oracle.Self-Managed.BinaryReaderPrivileges